# DuckDuckGo Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, web, vimperator, duckduckgo

I've recently installed [Vimperator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator) and it is a great thing leading me to remove the mouse and experience mouse-less browsing.

I've also replaced Google by [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/about) on Firefox so now I rely on its results to find things.

Vimperator's `Follow hint` activated by <kbd>J</kbd> doesn't seem to work well or at all on DuckDuckGo what I heavily rely on alongside the keyboard shortcuts of the web portals that I usually browse like Wikipedia and Stack Exchange.

So I'm seeking to find native or third-party, if any, keyboard shortcuts for DuckDuckGo, and also wonder if there's any way to *fix* Vimperator to work on [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/) as well.

Comment: :D Wow, can't believe I typed it wrong, must had a confused head when asking, immediately edited.

Comment: I'm confused because my `Follow hint` is activated by `F` and it works fine for me on DDG as it does for Google and searx.

Comment: I was on Windows when asking, but even in Fedora neither `f` nor `F` works on DDG. Although it works well with Google.

Comment: OK that's pretty strange - I guess that something is grabbing that keypress in DDG. Do all other normal mode navigations work?

Comment: Yeah, everything apart from Follow Links seem to work. I gave up searching on Google for DDG, but it lets me down :) while Google is perfectly ok with the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are alternative mappings available which might work for `f` and `F` using the hint `;`:

- Follow link: `f`, use `;o`
- Follow link in new tab: `F`, use `;t`

Hopefully the `;` won't "go missing" in the same way as it has on DDG for you - although I've not been able to replicate this behaviour on my Firefoxes.

Comment: Surprisingly it worked well :) I imagine, `o` stands for open, and `t` for tab, to better associate the keys with their function, as `f` opens the link in the current tab, while `F` in a new tab.

Answer (score 2):

In vimperator you can tap `I` to `:ignorekeys add  https?://duckduckgo\\.com/\\?q=.*`. This will make vimperator to automatically turn on ignorekeys mode whenever you enter duckduckgo and leave the mode once you leave the page. You can use `<Insert>` or ` to toggle the mode at any moment.

It makes it way more comfortable to use duckduckgo, since it's own shortcuts are aware of structure of the search engine. On the negative side, you need to learn [a few more keys](https://duck.co/help/features/keyboard-shortcuts)